# How can I make for the word border-bottom?

Tags: html, css

html code

```
<div class="title-content">
    <div class="h1">
        <h1><strong>stuff</strong></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

css code?

I need the css code and I want it in center of the bage while the border on under the word only and not all the line .

Comment: Sorry, I just cannot understand what you are wanting. what is 'word border bottom'?

Comment: border-bottom: 1px black solid;
that what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just the title characters to be underlined and not the whole width of the title class element, then a simple text-align center will do it with the h1 display setting changed and the border set on that.

```css
.title-content {
  text-align: center;
}

.h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-content">
  <div class="h1">
    <h1><strong>stuff</strong></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want more complex layout then probably investigating flex would be useful.

Comment: That  it , Thanks men

Answer (score 0):

You could add it to the `.title-content` class using CSS.

```css
.title-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.title-content h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-content">
    <div class="h1">
        <h1><strong>stuff</strong></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That will make all the line have border, I don`t want that

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: @SAYA Then you can do like this.

Comment: It solved thank you 

Comment: If the answer helped you then mark it as correct.